# JS глобальные переменные которыми воспользуется другой скрипт

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт, где куча input на главной странице и скрипт подсчета.

```
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), array = ['load', 'keyup'], i = array.length;
        while(i--)
        {
            window['on'+array[i]] = function()
            {
               function $(i)
               {
                    return ~~input[i].value;
               }

               input[100].value = $(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90);
               input[101].value = $(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91);
               input[102].value = $(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92);
               input[103].value = $(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93);
               input[104].value = $(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94);
               input[105].value = $(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95);
               input[106].value = $(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96);
               input[107].value = $(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97);
               input[108].value = $(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98);
               input[109].value = $(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99);


               input[110].value = (($(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90)) * 4.36).toFixed(0);
               input[111].value = (($(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91)) * 3.72).toFixed(0);
               input[112].value = (($(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92)) * 10.54).toFixed(0);
               input[113].value = (($(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
               input[114].value = (($(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94)) * 2.3).toFixed(0);
               input[115].value = (($(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95)) * 4.6).toFixed(0);
               input[116].value = (($(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96)) * 4.3).toFixed(0);
               input[117].value = (($(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97)) * 2.11).toFixed(0);  
               input[118].value = (($(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
               input[119].value = (($(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99)) * 6).toFixed(0);

               document.getElementById('str').value = $(100) + $(101) + $(102) + $(103) + $(104) + $(105) + $(106) + $(107) + $(108) + $(109);
               document.getElementById('itog').value = $(110) + $(111) + $(112) + $(113) + $(114) + $(115) + $(116) + $(117) + $(118) + $(119);

        };

    }
```

input[110] - input[119] в конце умножают на число. Хочется сделать страницу настроек, куда записываешь числа на которые умножать, а в этом скрипте подставляешь только n1,n2,n3 и т.д.. Это для удобства смены множителя, не прибегая к коду. Множители записать в localStorage.setItem. 
Интересует как реализовать сею штуку.
У сайта есть js файл. Приведенный скрипт находится в index.html.

---

```
function asd1(){
var voda1 = document.getElementById('voda').value;
return voda1;
```

}
Это находится в файле js и таких функций 10 каждая к своему полю.

А это уже в index.html

```
var k1 = asd1();
```

Но не работает. Я думаю в скрипте который первый я прикрепил к вопросу, вначале добавить переменных значением которых являются результаты функций. Уже эти переменные подставить на место второго множителя.

Comment: Не понятно, в чём именно сложность. Вам нужно добавить ещё 10 инпутов, чтобы они меняли значения множителей?

Comment: Ну и заголовок вопроса, КМК, не отражает смысла вопроса (если я его, вопрос, правильно понял). Глобальные переменные - это немного про другое.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, понял вопрос только после пятого прочтения примерно. Если я вас правильно понял, что нужно только подставлять нужные числа в функцию, то вот вариант.

Понятное дело, что эти все элементы (inputs и input[n].value) надо генерировать в цикле, но в этом примере не это главное.

Как эти значения записывать в/считывать из localStorage нужно объяснять?

```js
var multipliers = document.querySelectorAll(".multiplier"); 

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
  array = ['load', 'keyup'],
  i = array.length;
while (i--) {
  window['on' + array[i]] = function() {
    function $(i) {
      return ~~input[i].value;
    }
    
    var multiplierValues = [];
    multipliers.forEach(function (multiplier) {
      multiplierValues.push(~~multiplier.value);
    });

    input[100].value = $(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90);
    input[101].value = $(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91);
    input[102].value = $(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92);
    input[103].value = $(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93);
    input[104].value = $(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94);
    input[105].value = $(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95);
    input[106].value = $(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96);
    input[107].value = $(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97);
    input[108].value = $(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98);
    input[109].value = $(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99);


    input[110].value = (($(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90)) * multiplierValues[0]).toFixed(0);
    input[111].value = (($(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91)) * multiplierValues[1]).toFixed(0);
    input[112].value = (($(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92)) * multiplierValues[2]).toFixed(0);
    input[113].value = (($(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93)) * multiplierValues[3]).toFixed(0);
    input[114].value = (($(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94)) * multiplierValues[4]).toFixed(0);
    input[115].value = (($(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95)) * multiplierValues[5]).toFixed(0);
    input[116].value = (($(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96)) * multiplierValues[6]).toFixed(0);
    input[117].value = (($(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97)) * multiplierValues[7]).toFixed(0);
    input[118].value = (($(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98)) * multiplierValues[8]).toFixed(0);
    input[119].value = (($(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99)) * multiplierValues[9]).toFixed(0);

    document.getElementById('str').value = $(100) + $(101) + $(102) + $(103) + $(104) + $(105) + $(106) + $(107) + $(108) + $(109);
    document.getElementById('itog').value = $(110) + $(111) + $(112) + $(113) + $(114) + $(115) + $(116) + $(117) + $(118) + $(119);

  };

}
```

```css
.ugly-inputs-container, .ugly-multiplier-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.output-container {
  margin-bottom: 170px;
}

input {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ugly-inputs-container">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="ugly-multiplier-container">
  multipliers:<br/>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
  <input type="text" class="multiplier"></input>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="output-container">
  output:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="str"></input>
  <input type="text" id="itog"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Dan. У меня поля куда пишешь числа. Расположены они в столбик, каждый столбик складывается произведение умножается. Мне нужно Что бы я второй статичный множитель мог править не в коде, а у меня была страница "Настройки" где я в соответствующий столбику input введу число(второй множитель). Таким образом править можно было не в коде. А в скрипте получается вместо конкретной цифры, переменная. 
Как то так.

Comment: Вы мой пример изучили? Понятно, откуда значения множителей берутся?

Comment: > Расположены они в столбик, каждый столбик складывается произведение умножается.
- Насчёт столбиков и как это всё должно выглядеть - совсем непонятно. Если бы вы привели пример HTML кода, столбики бы выглядели как надо

Comment: На этой же странице я могу расположить и работать будет. Но мне надо на другой странице. И пользоваться с неё этими данными. Тут уже сложнее. Я добавил код, запусти посмотри как выглядит. Только на всю страницу открывай.

Comment: помоги пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Функция скрывает клавиатура по Enter
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(
  function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        this.blur();
      }
    })
  });
 
//Функция модального окна + очиска localStorage
 var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.showModal(); // открыть диалоговое окно
};

document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close(); // закрыть диалоговое окно
};

function divOp(type) { if (type == 1) { document.getElementById('menuBlock').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('blockLink').innerHTML='<a onclick="divOp(0);"><i class="fa fa-times fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
}
else {document.getElementById('menuBlock').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('blockLink').innerHTML='<a onclick="divOp(1);"><i class="blink-1 fa fa-tasks fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
}
}

function divOpItog() {  
document.getElementById('blockLinks').innerHTML='<a onclick="divOpItog();"><input class="colls" id="globalItog" type="number" /></a>';

}

function divOpSaveItog(type) { if (type == 1) { 
document.getElementById('blockLinkss').innerHTML='<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(0);"><button onclick="goMail()" class="modbutss">Да</button></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(0);"><button class="modbutss">Нет</button></a>';
}
else {
document.getElementById('blockLinkss').innerHTML='<a onclick="divOpSaveItog(1);"><button class="modbuts">Сохранить</button></a>';
}
}

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
 var ref = window.open('http://m.vk.com/id26294554', '_system', 'location=yes');
 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
 ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
 ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );
 background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
 font-weight: 600;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;
}
th {font: bold 14px sans-serif;}
td {padding: 5px;}
#sum {border: 1px solid red;}
form {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
dialog {
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   border-radius: 6px;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   background-color:#E4E4E4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );
}
dialog::backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.modbut {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 12px;
 background-color: #555555;
 padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.modbuts {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 12px;
 background-color: #555555;
 padding: 4px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.modbutss {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 12px;
 background-color: #555555;
 padding: 4px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.yes {
 font-weight: 600;
 border-radius: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #f44336;
 padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.yes:active {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
.no {
 font-weight: 600;
 border-radius: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.no:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
 display: none;
}
input[type=number]{
    width: 80px;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.col {
 background-color: #FFFFF0;
}
.coll {
 background-color: #F0FFF0;
}
.colls {
 background-color: #F0FFF0;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.colll {
 background-color: #F4FAFF;
}
.collld {
 background-color: #FFF4F4;
 width: 72px;
}
#s1, #s2, #s3, #s4, #s5, #s6, #s7, #s8, #s9, #s10, #s11, #s12, #s13, #s14, #s15, #s16, #s17, #s18, #s19, #s20 {
 background-color: #F4FAFF;
 width: 46px;
}
.fa-tasks
{
 content: "\f0ae";
 color: #006C00;

}
.fa-bars
{
 content: "\f0c9";
 color: #008000;
}
.fa-times
{
 content: "\f00d";
 color:#C30;
}
.fa-user
{
  content: "\f007";
  color:#232323;
}
.fa-calendar
{
  content: "\f073";
  color:#232323;
}
.fa-calculator
{
  content: "\f1ec";
  color:#232323;
}
.fa-vk
{
 content: "\f189";
 color: #0059B3;
}
.fa-at
{
 content: "\f1fa";
 color: #E9D803;
}
.menu-open
{
 list-style: none;
 position: fixed; /* Фиксированное положение */
    right: 64px; /* Расстояние от правого края окна браузера */
 bottom: 0; /* Расстояние снизу */
}
.mainMenu
{
 position: fixed; /* Фиксированное положение */
    right: 22px; /* Расстояние от правого края окна браузера */
 bottom: 16px;; /* Расстояние снизу */
}
.button {
 background-color: #999999; /* Green */
 border: none;
 border-radius: 12px;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 4px 2px;
 width: 160px;
 outline: none;
}
.button2
{
 outline: none;
 padding: 10px 10px;
}
.author-content
{
 padding:16px 16px 16px 16px;
 text-transform: none;
}
.blink-1 {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  40% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<title>KDV assistant</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Вода(4.36)</th>
  <th>Мука(3.72)</th>
  <th>Яйца(10.54)</th>
  <th>Чай(2.98)</th>
  <th>Бабы(2.3)</th>
  <th>Пиво(4.6)</th>
  <th>Элит.(4.3)</th>
  <th>Колб.(2.11)</th>
  <th>Мол.(2.98)</th>
  <th>Овощи(6)</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">1</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t1" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t2" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t3" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t4" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t5" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t6" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t7" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t8" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t9" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t10" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">2</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t11" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t12" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t13" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t14" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t15" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t16" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t17" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t18" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t19" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t20" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">3</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t21" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t22" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t23" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t24" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t25" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t26" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t27" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t28" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t29" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t30" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">4</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t31" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t32" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t33" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t34" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t35" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t36" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t37" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t38" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t39" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t40" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">5</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t41" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t42" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t43" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t44" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t45" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t46" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t47" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t48" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t49" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t50" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">6</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t51" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t52" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t53" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t54" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t55" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t56" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t57" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t58" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t59" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t60" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">7</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t61" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t62" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t63" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t64" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t65" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t66" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t67" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t68" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t69" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t70" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">8</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t71" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t72" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t73" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t74" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t75" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t76" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t77" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t78" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t79" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t80" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">9</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t81" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t82" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t83" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t84" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t85" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t86" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t87" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t88" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t89" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t90" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600; text-align:center;">10</td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t91" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t92" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t93" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t94" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t95" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t96" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t97" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t98" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t99" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="colll" id="t100" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600;">Строки</td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600;">Деньги</td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
  <td><input class="col" type="number" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600;">Итого строк</td>
  <td><input class="coll" type="number" id="str" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight: 600;">Итого денег</td>
  <td><input class="coll" type="number" id="itog" /></td>
        <td colspan="3"><div id="blockLinkss"><a onClick="divOpSaveItog(1);"><button class="modbuts">Сохранить</button></a></div></td>
 </tr>
</table>  
<dialog>
 <p style="text-align:center; font-size:16px; font-weight: 600;">Точно очистить?</p>
 <button class="yes" id="resetSbor">Да</button>
 <button class="no" id="close">Нет</button>
</dialog>
<button class="modbut" id="show">Очистить</button>
<div class="mainMenu">
 <div id="blockLink"><a onClick="divOp(1);"><i class="blink-1 fa fa-tasks fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
</div>
<div id="menuBlock" style="display:none;">
 <ul class="menu-open">
  <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'index.html'"><i class="fa fa-calculator fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Сборка</button></li>
  <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'stats.html'"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Итоги по дням</button></li>
  <li><button class="button button2" onClick="location.href = 'author.html'"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;О программе</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--Функция умножения и вывода полей input--> 
<script>
 var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), array = ['load', 'keyup'], i = array.length;
     while(i--)
  {
         window['on'+array[i]] = function()
   {
            function $(i)
      {
                 return ~~input[i].value;
            }
      
      input[100].value = $(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90);
            input[101].value = $(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91);
            input[102].value = $(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92);
      input[103].value = $(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93);
      input[104].value = $(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94);
      input[105].value = $(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95);
      input[106].value = $(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96);
      input[107].value = $(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97);
      input[108].value = $(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98);
      input[109].value = $(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99);
      
      
            input[110].value = (($(0) + $(10) + $(20) + $(30) + $(40) + $(50) + $(60) + $(70) + $(80) + $(90)) * 4.36).toFixed(0);
            input[111].value = (($(1) + $(11) + $(21) + $(31) + $(41) + $(51) + $(61) + $(71) + $(81) + $(91)) * 3.72).toFixed(0);
            input[112].value = (($(2) + $(12) + $(22) + $(32) + $(42) + $(52) + $(62) + $(72) + $(82) + $(92)) * 10.54).toFixed(0);
      input[113].value = (($(3) + $(13) + $(23) + $(33) + $(43) + $(53) + $(63) + $(73) + $(83) + $(93)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
      input[114].value = (($(4) + $(14) + $(24) + $(34) + $(44) + $(54) + $(64) + $(74) + $(84) + $(94)) * 2.3).toFixed(0);
      input[115].value = (($(5) + $(15) + $(25) + $(35) + $(45) + $(55) + $(65) + $(75) + $(85) + $(95)) * 4.6).toFixed(0);
      input[116].value = (($(6) + $(16) + $(26) + $(36) + $(46) + $(56) + $(66) + $(76) + $(86) + $(96)) * 4.3).toFixed(0);
      input[117].value = (($(7) + $(17) + $(27) + $(37) + $(47) + $(57) + $(67) + $(77) + $(87) + $(97)) * 2.11).toFixed(0);  
      input[118].value = (($(8) + $(18) + $(28) + $(38) + $(48) + $(58) + $(68) + $(78) + $(88) + $(98)) * 2.98).toFixed(0);
      input[119].value = (($(9) + $(19) + $(29) + $(39) + $(49) + $(59) + $(69) + $(79) + $(89) + $(99)) * 6).toFixed(0);

      document.getElementById('str').value = $(100) + $(101) + $(102) + $(103) + $(104) + $(105) + $(106) + $(107) + $(108) + $(109);
      document.getElementById('itog').value = $(110) + $(111) + $(112) + $(113) + $(114) + $(115) + $(116) + $(117) + $(118) + $(119);

     };

 }
</script>
<!--Функция сохранения данных localStorage-->
 <script>
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, number');
 function checkValidity() {};
 for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
 {
  (function(element)
  {
   var id = element.getAttribute('id');
   element.value = localStorage.getItem(id); // обязательно наличие у элементов id
   element.oninput = function()
   {
    localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
    checkValidity();
   };
  })(elements[i]);
 }
</script>
<!-- обновление страницы и очищение хранилища-->
<script>
document.querySelector('#resetSbor').onclick = function() {
 for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {
  var n = "t" + i;
  localStorage.removeItem(n);
 }
 location.reload(true);
};
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function goMail() {
        
            document.location = "stats.html?id=" + document.getElementById("itog").value;
        
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот так это выглядит. 
Нужно добавить ссылку настройки. На той станице 10 инпутов где и нужно вписать множители. Сохранить их в localStorage. И именно ими пользоваться с главной страницы.